# Celery not revoked tasks

Tags: python, django, celery, celery-task

I have a task on Celery 4.1. I want to revoke this task like

```
task.revoke()
```

all is nang up on this time, then I raise `KeyboardInterrupt` and have the same Traceback:

```
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 164, in get
    self.not_empty.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
```

After that, I can revoke tasks.

full traceback with gevent.
I'm also try to change broker to RabbitMQ and has the same error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/backend/tests.py", line 779, in test_reactivate_contract
    contract.activate_contract(paid=True, reactivate=True)
  File "/usr/src/app/backend/models/contract.py", line 83, in activate_contract
    revoke_task(self.celery_task)
  File "/usr/src/app/backend/celery/tasks.py", line 128, in revoke_task
    app.control.revoke(task_id)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 210, in revoke
    }, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/celery/app/control.py", line 436, in broadcast
    limit, callback, channel=channel,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 315, in _broadcast
    serializer=serializer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 285, in _publish
    with self.producer_or_acquire(producer, chan) as producer:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/pidbox.py", line 247, in producer_or_acquire
    with self.producer_pool.acquire() as producer:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/resource.py", line 83, in acquire
    R = self.prepare(R)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/pools.py", line 62, in prepare
    p = p()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 203, in __call__
    return self.evaluate()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/utils/functional.py", line 206, in evaluate
    return self._fun(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/pools.py", line 42, in create_producer
    conn = self._acquire_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/pools.py", line 39, in _acquire_connection
    return self.connections.acquire(block=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kombu/resource.py", line 78, in acquire
    R = self._resource.get(block=block, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/queue.py", line 164, in get
    self.not_empty.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 295, in wait
    waiter.acquire()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/thread.py", line 84, in acquire
    return BoundedSemaphore.acquire(self, blocking, timeout)
  File "src/gevent/_semaphore.py", line 198, in gevent._semaphore.Semaphore.acquire (src/gevent/gevent._semaphore.c:4541)
  File "src/gevent/_semaphore.py", line 226, in gevent._semaphore.Semaphore.acquire (src/gevent/gevent._semaphore.c:4367)
  File "src/gevent/_semaphore.py", line 166, in gevent._semaphore.Semaphore._do_wait (src/gevent/gevent._semaphore.c:3562)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gevent/hub.py", line 630, in switch
    return RawGreenlet.switch(self)
gevent.hub.LoopExit: ('This operation would block forever', <Hub at 0x7fd1b0269210 epoll default pending=0 ref=0 fileno=4 resolver=<gevent.resolver_thread.Resolver at 0x7fd1a7843c50 pool=<ThreadPool at 0x7fd1a78432b0 0/1/10>> threadpool=<ThreadPool at 0x7fd1a78432b0 0/1/10>>)
```

I'm using Python 3.6, Celery 4.1, Django 1.11, and Redis.

Comment: What does "all is nang up on this time" mean?

Comment: A traceback is far less helpful if you post just a portion from the middle of it.

Comment: i've add the traceback. Also i try to change broker.